# Seemingly valid SRS-processed message is being rejected by gmail servers

Tags: postfix, gmail, dmarc

I have a virtual private server with its own IP and have configured SPF, DKIM, DMARC, SRS (with `postsrsd`) and all that jazz. Let's call it `domainut.com`.

Most things are working, mail is being delivered to gmail --to the spam folder, because the IP doesn't yet have any reputation, but that should improve over time.

However, while doing some tests I ended up receiving a mail from no-reply@microsoft.com which was being redirected to myself@gmail.com and also myself@vanity-domain.com

The gmail server complained:

`(...) status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[108.177.127.27] said: 
550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from microsoft.com is not accepted due to 
550-5.7.1 domain's DMARC policy. Please contact the administrator of 
550-5.7.1 microsoft.com domain if this was a legitimate mail. Please visit 
550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about the 
550 5.7.1 DMARC initiative. s19-v6si278495edc.383 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))`

However, the SRS seems to be working correctly, as I can see in the mail headers:

`Return-Path: <SRS0=N0AY=LS=microsoft.com=no-reply@domainut.com>
Delivered-To: <myself@vanity-domain.com>
Received: from ...
  by ...
  for ...
Received-SPF: Pass (sender SPF authorized) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; helo=mail.domainut.com; envelope-from=srs0=n0ay=ls=microsoft.com=no-reply@domainut.com; receiver=myself@vanity-domain.com`

I may have some misunderstanding on what should the SRS do, or what is expected to do gmail with that kind of mail.

What should I fix in order to happily forward mails sent to the domainut.com to myself@gmail.com?

[Meta: I wanted to add the tag SRS, given that it seems to be the key issue with that problem, but it seems that it doesn't exist yet]

Comment: AFAIK there is no good "fix" for this except to have Gmail pull your mail from your server, rather than trying to forward it.

Answer (score 0):

The key information is currently not available in the headers you've specified. The DMARC result is based on the 'From' header of the message.

What is the value of that header in this example message?

DMARC required alignment on the 'From:' header and either SPF or DKIM. I don't see and DKIM headers, but based on the 'Return-Path' header I currently assume you're using a different 'From:' header then the SPF domain as specified in the 'Return-Path' header, is that correct?